# SQL Server custom record sort in table, allowing to delete records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sorting

SQL Server table with custom sort has columns: **ID** (PK, auto-increment), **OrderNumber**, **Col1**, **Col2**..

By default an insert trigger copies value from ID to OrderNumber as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/848182/475861).
Using some visual interface, user can sort records by incrementing or decrementing OrderNumber values.

However, how to deal with records being deleted in the meantime?

**Example:**
Say you add records with PK ID: 1,2,3,4,5 - OrderNumber receives same values. Then you delete records with ID=4,ID=5. Next record will have ID=6 and OrderNumber will receive the same value. **Having a span of 2 missing OrderNumbers would force user to decrement record with ID=6 like 3 times to change it's order** (i.e. 3x button pressed).

Alternatively, one could insert `select count(*) from table` into OrderNumber, but it would allow to have several similar values in table, when some old rows are deleted.

If one doesn't delete records, but only "deactivate" them, they're still included in sort order, just invisible for user. At the moment, solution in Java is needed, but I think the issue is language-independent.

Is there a better approach at this?

Comment: I realise that this may sound irrelevant but how is your change of order implemented at the moment? You are talking about the necessity of decrementing the `OrderNumber` value multiple times instead of just once. But if you only needed to decrement it only once, how would that work? Certainly you would also need to *increment* `OrderNumber` in a different row (perhaps the one with `OrderNumber=5`), wouldn't you? Is that how you do it? If so, *where* do you do that, in SQL or in the application? If in SQL, could you show the script?

Comment: @AndriyM After checking (in java servlet) if the row is not the first or last one, I'm running two SQL UPDATE queries that switch the OrderNumber of these 2 elements. So, for now, it's only 1-element shift. I guess if I were to move element by several places, I'd need to update all OrderNumbers between start and end point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply modify the script that switches the `OrderNumber` values so it does it correctly *without* relying on their being without gaps.

I don't know what arguments your script accepts and how it uses them, but the one that I've eventually come up with accept the ID of the item to move and the number of positions to move by (a negative value would mean "toward the lower `OrderNumber` values", and a positive one would imply the opposite direction).

The idea is as follows:

1. Look up the specified item's `OrderNumber`.
2. Rank all the items starting from `OrderNumber` in the direction determined by the second argument. The specified item thus receives the ranking of `1`.
3. Pick the items with rankings from `1` to the one that is the absolute value of the second argument plus one. (I.e. the last item is the one where the specified item is being moved to.)
4. Join the resulting set with itself so that every row is joined with the next one and the last row is joined with the first one and thus use one set of rows to update the other.

This is the query that implements the above, with comments explaining some tricky parts:

<sub>**Edited: fixed an issue with incorrect reordering**</sub>

```
/* these are the arguments of the query */
DECLARE @ID int, @JumpBy int;
SET @ID = ...
SET @JumpBy = ...

DECLARE @OrderNumber int;
/* Step #1: Get OrderNumber of the specified item */
SELECT @OrderNumber = OrderNumber FROM atable WHERE ID = @ID;

WITH ranked AS (
  /* Step #2: rank rows including the specified item and those that are sorted
     either before or after it (depending on the value of @JumpBy */
  SELECT
    *,
    rnk = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      ORDER BY OrderNumber * SIGN(@JumpBy)
      /* this little "* SIGN(@JumpBy)" trick ensures that the
         top-ranked item will always be the one specified by @ID:
         * if we are selecting rows where OrderNumber >= @OrderNumber,
           the order will be by OrderNumber and @OrderNumber will be
           the smallest item (thus #1);
         * if we are selecting rows where OrderNumber <= @OrderNumber,
           the order becomes by -OrderNumber and @OrderNumber again
           becomes the top ranked item, because its negative counterpart,
           -@OrderNumber, will again be the smallest one
      */
    )
  FROM atable
  WHERE OrderNumber >= @OrderNumber AND @JumpBy > 0
     OR OrderNumber <= @OrderNumber AND @JumpBy < 0
),
affected AS (
  /* Step #3: select only rows that need be affected */
  SELECT *
  FROM ranked
  WHERE rnk BETWEEN 1 AND ABS(@JumpBy) + 1
)
/* Step #4: self-join and update */
UPDATE old
SET OrderNumber = new.OrderNumber
FROM affected old
  INNER JOIN affected new ON old.rnk = new.rnk % (ABS(@JumpBy) + 1) + 1
            /* if old.rnk = 1, the corresponding new.rnk is N,
               because 1 = N MOD N + 1  (N is ABS(@JumpBy)+1),
               for old.rnk = 2 the matching new.rnk is 1: 2 = 1 MOD N + 1,
               for 3, it's 2 etc.
               this condition could alternatively be written like this:
               new.rnk = (old.rnk + ABS(@JumpBy) - 1) % (ABS(@JumpBy) + 1) + 1
             */
```

Note: this assumes SQL Server 2005 or later version.

One known issue with this solution is that it will not "move" rows correctly if the specified ID cannot be moved exactly by the specified number of positions (for instance, if you want to move the topmost row up by any number of positions, or the second row by two or more positions etc.).

Comment: Impressive sorting solution, but what about insert and delete? When I delete some record from few hours ago. What OrderNumber do I assign to new record if there are gaps? Can't really be ID and can't be count(*)  I guess.

Comment: When rows are inserted, initialise their OrderNumbers with their IDs, like I understand you are doing now. If rows are deleted, do nothing about OrderNumbers. This solution is supposed to deal with OrderNumbers as they are, even if there are gaps. I.e. if an OrderNumber has a value of `10` and the immediately preceding OrderNumber is `7` and you need the two to trade places, this script will do that correctly. You just need to specify the ID of one of the two items and the number of positions to shift (either 1 or -1 in this case, depending on which item you specify).

Comment: Right, it totally ignores gaps. A bit different approach than what I was thinking about. I'll check this soon, thank you.

Comment: Somehow it doesn't work correctly.. Worked for few simple cases but when IDs got mixed up they either don't move at all or different rows get moved, i.e. ID=1,JumpBy=2 changed ID order from 1,2,3 to 3,1,2 (while it should be 2,3,1 - IDs had gaps). I think I found a different solution.

Comment: @yosh: I mixed up the aliases, `old` and `new`, in the join condition of the UPDATE statement. Fixed the code and also added a note about a known issue.

Comment: Yea, noticed that old/new. The idea is great, but I had some troubles with mixed up values even in the middle of the record list. I'd surely follow this solution if I needed to move records by more than 1 row. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok - if I'm not mistaken, you want to defragment your OrderNumber.
What if you use `ROW_NUMBER()` for this ?

Example:

```
;WITH calc_cte AS (
  SELECT
    ID
    , OrderNumber
    , RowNo = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID)
  FROM
    dbo.Order    
)
UPDATE
  c
SET
  OrderNumber = c.RowNo
FROM
  calc_cte c
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted i WHERE c.ID = i.ID)
```

Comment: Something I should run it after every delete to "patch" missing records. But it doesn't really solve much.. How do I get next OrderNumber to input with next insert? ID might be way higher than current OrderNumber and count(*) problem with multiple similar values isn't really solved.

Comment: Perhaps the rows should be ranked by `OrderNumber` instead of by `ID`, or the order is going to be reset with every INSERT (or what was it you intended this to run on, certainly not on DELETE, judging by the use of `inserted`).

Comment: Maybe that would be a solution.. After every delete (more likely max 5 records deleted per week) assign again OrderNumber to each element. However, like @AndriyM noticed, rows should be ordered by old OrderNumber column. Though, I'm not sure if updating several thousand rows with every delete wouldn't be a bit of overkill..

Answer (score 0):

Didn't want to reply my own question, but I believe I have found a solution.

**Insert query:**

```
INSERT INTO table (OrderNumber, col1, col2) 
VALUES ((select count(*)+1 from table),val1,val2)
```

**Delete trigger:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER Cleanup_After_Delete ON table
AFTER DELETE AS
BEGIN
  WITH rowtable AS (SELECT [ID], OrderNumber, rownum = ROW_NUMBER() 
                    OVER (ORDER BY OrderNumber ASC) FROM table)
  UPDATE rt SET OrderNumber = rt.rownum FROM rowtable rt 
  WHERE OrderNumber >= (SELECT OrderNumber FROM deleted)
END
```

The trigger fires up after every delete and corrects all OrderNumbers above the deleted one (no gaps). This means that I can simply change the order of 2 records by switching their OrderNumbers.

---

This is a working solution for my problem, however [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11330364/475861) is also very good one, perhaps more useful for others.