# Stored procedure to re-order rows in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have been tasked with the creation of a custom stored procedure:

```
exec UPDATE_PROJECT_ORDER @PROJECTID=12, @UPDATEMODE=0
```

That will execute after a row in a table has been updated.

Unfortunately it has me really stumped (to the point that I'm not even sure if it is possible) I have been trying to simplify what I am doing and wondered if I could ask the board for assistance on just the code itself...

So the purpose of the stored procedure / code is to re-order a list of items generally in a sequential order, the re-ordering changes based on a passed in parameter which will either leave the value as it is set in the table by the user and order the rest of the list around it or renumber it as the next number in the sequence. I think we can assume that UPDATEMODE=0 is going to be default most of the time.

I have a table that looks like this:

```
---------------------------------------
|   ID   |   POSITION   |   OLD_POS   |
---------------------------------------
|   10   |     1        |             |
|   11   |     2        |             |
|   12   |     3        |             |
|   13   |     4        |             |
---------------------------------------
```

If the user decides to give the record with ID 12 (ID is being passed in with the stored procedure) a higher priority, for example 1, then what should happen is the other records (10 / 11 / 13) should be sequentially re-ordered around it (2 / 3 / 4) which will affect how they are displayed in the front end, e.g.

```
---------------------------------------
|   ID   |   POSITION   |   OLD_POS   |
---------------------------------------
|   10   |     2        |      1      |
|   11   |     3        |      2      |
|   12   |     1        |      3      |
|   13   |     4        |      4      |
---------------------------------------
```

Another example of this would be the position of record ID 12 is changed to from a 1 to a 7 so this data set:

```
---------------------------------------
|   ID   |   POSITION   |   OLD_POS   |
---------------------------------------
|   10   |     2        |      1      |
|   11   |     3        |      2      |
|   12   |     1/7      |      3      |
|   13   |     4        |      4      |
---------------------------------------
```

The position data is re-ordered as:

```
---------------------------------------
|   ID   |   POSITION   |   OLD_POS   |
---------------------------------------
|   10   |     1        |      2      |
|   11   |     2        |      3      |
|   12   |     7        |      1      |
|   13   |     3        |      4      |
---------------------------------------
```

As mentioned above - in the the stored procedure there is the requirement that another parameter be passed in (@UPDATEMODE which can be 0 or 1) that changes the behavior of the function allowing the user to specify what position they want and re-order the list around it versus making it the next number in the sequence, for example they update the priority in row 3 from value 1 to value 7

This data set row 12 position value = 1 but is changed to 7 with UPDATEMODE specified as 1:

```
---------------------------------------
|   ID   |   POSITION   |   OLD_POS   |
---------------------------------------
|   10   |     2        |      1      |
|   11   |     3        |      2      |
|   12   |     1/7      |      3      |
|   13   |     4        |      4      |
---------------------------------------
```

Which would re-order the list as follows:

```
---------------------------------------
|   ID   |   POSITION   |   OLD_POS   |
---------------------------------------
|   10   |     1        |      2      |
|   11   |     2        |      3      |
|   12   |     4        |      1      |
|   13   |     3        |      4      |
---------------------------------------
```

In this example the stored procedure would be called as:

```
exec UPDATE_PROJECT_ORDER @PROJECTID=12, @UPDATEMODE=1
```

This is the SQL code I have been working with:

```
-- Declare variables
DECLARE @PROJECTID INTEGER
DECLARE @CURRENTPOSITION INTEGER
DECLARE @ROLLBACKPOSITION INTEGER
DECLARE @STARTPOSITION INTEGER
DECLARE @ENDPOSITION INTEGER

-- For testing hardcode a REQUEST ID
SET @PROJECTID = 12

-- Start Position value
SET @STARTPOSITION = 1

-- End Position value
SELECT @ENDPOSITION = COUNT(ID) FROM PROJECT WHERE PROJECT_ORDER IS NOT NULL

-- Update Rollback column with current value    
UPDATE PROJECT SET OLD_POS = POSITION WHERE POSITION IS NOT NULL

DECLARE cursorProjectPositionUpdate CURSOR fast_forward
FOR 
    SELECT ID, POSITION, OLD_POS
    FROM PROJECT 
    WHERE ID = @PROJECTID
    AND POSITION IS NOT NULL
OPEN cursorProjectPositionUpdate
FETCH NEXT FROM cursorProjectPositionUpdate INTO @PROJECTID, @CURRENTPOSITION, @ROLLBACKPOSITION

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN   
        WHILE (@STARTPOSITION <= @ENDPOSITION)
            IF @STARTPOSITION = 1
                UPDATE PROJECT
                SET POSITION = @STARTPOSITION
                WHERE ID = @PROJECTID
                    AND OLD_POSITION = @ROLLBACKPOSITION

            ELSE
                UPDATE PROJECT
                SET POSITION = @STARTPOSITION
                WHERE OLD_POS = @ROLLBACKPOSITION
                    AND ID <> @PROJECTID
        SET @STARTPOSITION = @STARTPOSITION + 1
        FETCH NEXT FROM cursorProjectPositionUpdate INTO @PROJECTID, @CURRENTPOSITION, @ROLLBACKPOSITION
    END
CLOSE cursorProjectPositionUpdate
DEALLOCATE cursorProjectPositionUpdate
```

I've used a cursor because there is a hard limit of 25 records max to be re-ordered so I'm not overly worried about performance. Although there maybe more than 25 records in the table which is why I have tried to exclude records with the AND POSITION IS NOT NULL clause so I hope this is acceptable.

The thought in my head is to count how many records I have total that have a position and then loop through setting the first to position 1 and then after that the rest to the next sequential order.

The biggest problem I am finding is on the matching of records, i.e. my WHERE clause, because the only thing being passed in by the stored procedure is the ID that I want to be set to position 1 so how do I know which one comes next... the logic is it should be the next lowest ID number working down the list.

This is being done in MS SQL Server.

I am trying to avoid creating any temporary tables so need to see if this can be done all in one.

Hopefully this makes some sort of sense to someone, I am open to solutions and will share as much information as I can.

Many thanks!

---

**Additional**

I have been thinking about this a little more based on the below answers, again I am trying to keep this as simple as possible to start with so I have the stored procedure which passed in a PROJECT ID value so how about if I loop through all of the values I have that do not match my PROJECT ID resetting them starting at 2 going up to my end point which is based on the number of records I have and once those are in sequence set the position of the passed in to project to 1. I know this doesn't cater for my update mode option but I'm worried thats just adding to much complication.

So as far as code goes what are your thoughts on something like:

```
-- Declare variables
DECLARE @PROJECTID INTEGER
DECLARE @STARTPOSITION INTEGER
DECLARE @ENDPOSITION INTEGER

-- Hardcoded for testing
SET @PROJECTID = 25061

-- Start Position value
SET @STARTPOSITION = 2

-- End Position value
SELECT @ENDPOSITION = COUNT(ID) FROM PROJECT WHERE PROJECT_ORDER IS NOT NULL AND ID <> @PROJECTID 

-- Update Rollback column with current value    
UPDATE PROJECT SET PROJECT_ORDER_RB = PROJECT_ORDER WHERE PROJECT_ORDER IS NOT NULL

-- Loop other records
WHILE (@STARTPOSITION <= @ENDPOSITION)
    UPDATE PROJECT SET PROJECT_ORDER = @STARTPOSITION WHERE ID <> @PROJECTID 
        AND PROJECT_ORDER IS NOT NULL AND (PROJECT_ORDER = 1 OR PROJECT_ORDER => @STARTPOSITION OR PROJECT_ORDER <= @ENDPOSITION)
SET @STARTPOSITION = @STARTPOSITION + 1

-- Finally set passed in Project to Position 1
UPDATE PROJECT SET PROJECT_ORDER = 1 WHERE ID = @PROJECTID
```

Comment: Can you add variables to the stored procedure if needed? In order to do the second part I think you'd need another variable to specify the new position since it isn't going to be 1 by default. So for your example it would be "exec UPDATE_PROJECT_ORDER @ID=12, @POSITION=7, @UPDATEMODE=0"

Comment: So based on the scope I was given the answer is no additional variables cannot be added to the stored procedure. For the second part of it I believe I would need to exclude updating the passed in ID with SQL, i.e. WHERE ID <> @REQUEST, so it skips over it but again that doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me because you wouldn't want duplicates so some how the code has to ignore the passed in variable but not re-use it in the list.

Comment: Maybe this answer will be helpful in some way: [SQL Server custom record sort in table, allowing to delete records](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308096/sql-server-custom-record-sort-in-table-allowing-to-delete-records/11330364#11330364). The query, basically, rotates values in the sort column based on the arguments (and it is parametrised in a slightly different way than in your requirements).

Comment: ... Having procedures that do two things, based on a boolean variable, are evil.  You really should be writing two separate routines, named differently.  Also, if you want to avoid having to update every row in the table, use a strategy of 'inserted item is halfway between existing items' (ie the first item is at 0, the next one above that is at 2 ^ 16, etc).  This _may_ need to be rebalanced on occasion - but with 2bn values, that'll be awhile.

Comment: So I am looking over the answers provided below (thanks to all of you by the way) and I see a couple of things that are giving me some concerns over them. At this point I can't assume that I have any extra variables to play with so no startpos / endpos for example plus I have to pass in UPDATEMODE which by default will be 1 which mean that the supplied ID becomes position 1 and everything is re-ordered around it, if it is 0 then the value set for that ID will be left alone and everything will be re-ordered around it. I know this isn't ideal but its the scope I have been given.

Comment: Your mode 0 doesn't make any sense. You're saying that in mode zero nothing will happen. If that ID stays the same then everything else would stay the same. According to your example you want to update priority 3 to 7 you are inherently changing it from a current position to a future position. You need a relative point of reference otherwise your explanation is still lacking something.

Comment: Yes I'm sorry I am trying to translate my scope document... I have added to my initial post to try and clarify the difference between the two modes... my apologies that this is so disjointed.

Comment: Your description really sounds like views and not a stored procedure to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a single update statement, without needing an OLD_POS column or anything similar, and without any Loops, Cursors or other non-set oriented artifacts:

```
CREATE Proc UPDATE_PROJECT_ORDER 
(
    @ProjectID      As INT, 
    @StartPosition  As INT,
    @EndPosition    As INT
) As

;With
  cteProjectOld As
(
    SELECT  ID, 
            POSITION,
            Case WHEN POSITION = @StartPosition 
                THEN @EndPosition 
                ELSE POSITION       END As TempPosition,
            Case WHEN POSITION = @StartPosition 
                THEN 1 
                ELSE 0              END As Moved
    FROM    PROJECT
)
, cteProjectNew As
(
    SELECT  *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY TempPosition, Moved) As NewPosition
    FROM    cteProjectOld
)
UPDATE  cteProjectNew
SET     POSITION = NewPosition
WHERE   ID = @ProjectID
```

Comment: As above this assumes I can pass in a starting / ending position which I don't have ahead of time I need to figure them out from the data I have - apologies if I'm not explaining this very well but I am trying to stick to the scope I was given.

Comment: If you do not know what the new position is supposed to be then you cannot do this task, it's that simple.  If you do know what it is supposed to be, then my answer shows you how to do it.

Comment: @andrew.reynolds81 From your post "*..there is the requirement that .. the function allow[] the user to specify what position they want and re-order the list around it .., for example they update priority 3 to 7"  My example above does this.  How exactly is the user specifying this information to the stored procedure without an additional parameter?

Comment: Depending on how the stored procedure is called the new position will either be 1 or the value set in the database but isn't you code expecting them to be passed in by the stored procedure? So I would need to add some additional code to determine if startposition is 1 or the db column value and get endposition which can be calculated by the number of records in the table.

Comment: @andrew.reynolds81 you say "*the new position will either be 1 or the value set in the database*".  What ***value set in the database***?  What value are you talking about?!?  You cannot set a value in a database and call a stored procedure at the same time.  They are two separate things.

Comment: @RBarryYoung you don't need the starting position because that is inferred from the ProjectID.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Sorry I didn't really explain did I... there is a front end interface allowing the user to change the priority value, on doing so the record is updated and the and the stored procedure is executed. The stored procedure will have the ID value being passed in with it and the database will have the updated position value and the rollback value if there is one.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a mode, you can just set the default new position = 1 so if you want to do the first mode you would only enter the ID and if you wanted to do the second mode you'd specify the additional variable.

```
Create  Proc update_project_order (@ID Int, @NewPosition Int = 1)
As

Declare @OldPosition Int,
        @Direction Int

Select  @OldPosition = Position
From    tableName
Where   ID = @ID

Set     @Direction =    Case 
                        When    @OldPosition < @NewPosition Then 0
                        When    @OldPosition > @NewPosition Then 1
                        Else    -1
                        End

Update  t
Set     Old_Pos =   Position,
        Position =  Case
                    When    ID = @ID Then @NewPosition
                    When    @Direction = 0 And 
                            Position Between @OldPosition And @NewPosition Then Position - 1
                    When    @Direction = 1 And 
                            Position Between @NewPosition And @OldPosition Then Position + 1
                    Else    Position
                    End
From    tableName t
```

Comment: This has been tested and works as desired, it's pretty much the implementation of @usr explanation except it takes direction into consideration since you either want to increment or decrement depending on which.

Comment: @andrew.reynolds81 does this take care of what you need? I can provide the test data I used, but I think this should do what you need in this form.

Comment: I'm looking over it now... it looks close here is what I am seeing - if I have 4 rows in my table ordered by position 1 / 2 /3 /4 and I want row 3 to be position 1 my data gets re-ordered as 2 / 3 / 1 / 4 which is exactly what I am looking for but if I have my position data as 4 / 3 / 2 / 1 it gets resorted 4 / 3 / 1 / 2 so only the last two are sorted.

Comment: That's because you're moving row three (which is position 2) to position 1. That would mean only position 1 would increment. That is correct by my understanding of your issue. What is your expected results in that scenario?

Comment: Expected result for a data set of the following positions 4 / 3 / 2 / 1 is that when setting row 3 (value = 2) to 1 it would be resorted as 2 / 3 / 1 / 4

Comment: Really? This will only ever give you the ability to prioritize or define the position of one record at a time ever. Let's say you have 1-100 ID with matching 1-100 position. In my way if you flip 95 to position 1 and then flip 50 to 1 the order would be ID:50,Pos:1; ID:95,Pos:2; ID:1,Pos:3; ID:2,Pos:4 ... with your way the second you flip ID 50 to Pos 1 it would set ID 95 back to Pos 95. This is what you want?

Comment: So this is where the UPDATEMODE parameter comes into play, the front end form is a drop-down list containing values 1-25 these are the available priorities. Lets say a user changes the project order from 1 to 7, i.e. it was 2 / 3 / 1 / 4 it becomes 2 / 3 / 7 / 4, the scope states that for UPDATEMODE = 0 the sequence would become 1 / 2 / 7 / 3 but UPDATEMODE = 1 the sequence becomes 1 / 2 / 4 / 3 which now that I'm re-reading on more sleep means the new value would never automatically jump to the top of the list it would either be in order or the next in sequence.

Comment: This one worked for me. I did however have to add a where clause to the update statement as i didnt want to modify everything in the table. Otherwise this worked great. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you can implement this as a two-step process:

1. Increment the position values for all items which have a position that is equal or greater than the target position and smaller that the old position
2. Update the item that should be moved to have the target position

You can do this with two update statements or even one if you cram a little `CASE` logic into it.

Comment: This seems to make sense to me and I have tried to add some simple code to my original question that will do this, my only question from this is how I would deal with my updatemode scenario when it is set to the other option. The other option doesn't promote to position one instead it just orders the list around the value set by the user but if I could get at least some of this problem solved that would be a plus.

Answer (score 0):

I think of this as two separate possibilities, either moving up the list or down the list.  The rest is just arithmetic on the position, which can be done inside a single update statement.

```
create procedure update_project_order (@ProjectId int, @UpdateMode int default 1)
begin

    declare @ProjectIdPosition int;
    select @ProjectIdPostion = Position
    from t
    where ProjectId = @ProjectId;

    if (@UpdateMode < @ProjectIdPosition)  -- Moving up the list
        update t
            set position = (case when position < @UpdateMode
                                 then position
                                 when position < @ProjectIdPosition
                                 then position + 1
                                 when ProjectId = @ProjectId
                                 then @UpdateMode
                                 when position
                            end);
    else if @UpdateMode > @ProjectIdPosition  -- Moving down the list
        update t
            set position = (case when position < @ProjectIdPostion
                                 then position
                                 when position < @UpdateMode
                                 then position - 1
                                 when ProjectId = @ProjectId
                                 then @UpdateMode
                                 else position
                            end);
end;
```

Note:  I haven't tested this.  It is an idea on how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Create Procedure UPDATE_PROJECT_ORDER (@ID int,@Posi int) as
begin

Select Cast(ID as int) as ID,POSITION,Identity(int ,1,1) as NewPos
into #tmp
from Project
where POSITION<=@Posi 
order by POSITION

Select Cast(ID as int) as ID,POSITION,Identity(int ,1,1)   as NewPos
into #tmp2
from Project
where POSITION>=@Posi 
order by POSITION



Update Project set Project.POSITION=#tmp.NewPos 
from #tmp 
where #tmp.ID=Project.ID

Update Project set Project.POSITION=#tmp2.NewPos + @Posi
from #tmp2 
where #tmp2.ID=Project.ID


Update Project set POSITION=@Posi where ID=@ID

Drop table #tmp
Drop table #tmp2
end
```

Comment: Thanks - this is using temporary tables which I can't assume I have permissions to create as the scope does state that I should not be using them.

Comment: All users have permissions to create local or global temporary tables in TempDB because this is assigned to them via the GUEST  user security context.  http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/temporary-tables-in-sql-server/

Comment: Thanks for the link a lot of good information in it... but doesn't your solution require a position to passed into the stored procedure? That's not something I have access to so the new position would have to be looked up from the database using the PROJECT ID field but then won't the position end up being the same value in your WHERE clause meaning the list won't re-order?

Comment: You should know the Project ID and the desired position, if it should be the first you could use : Select @Posi=MIN(Position) from Project. MAX for the last. Anything else is up to you